# How do I open an Android app's .APK file to update underlying code?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, react-native

My app is developed in react-native and the third party app provider are charging to implement the code for deep-linking.Though they have shared the .APK file with me.Through some videos & google search,I have learned that I will be able to do it by myself.I want to add deep-linking code in the AndroidManifest.xml file but how to open .apk in Android Studio and how to generate .apk file again once the changes are complete after testing on virtual device.

If you think that there will be issues by approaching through .APK file or its not the best way/standard process to achieve this ,then,please suggest me that what I need to ask them to share with me so that it can be imported in Android Studio without any issues and I can do some coding & test it and again generate .apk file to upload it on Google Play Store.

Comment: You can decompile the apk, but that code wont be exactly the same as original code, or even buildable from the start.

Comment: If you think that there will be issues by approaching through .APK file or its not the best way/standard process to achieve this ,then,please suggest me that what I need to ask them to share with me so that it can be imported in Android Studio without any issues and I can do some coding & test it.

Comment: You need source code & you can use firebase for deep linking.

Comment: Sure,Thanks.But please tell me the specific word for which I can ask the team and they don't give me something else.
Also please share the Firebase deep-link references and what are the prerequisite so that I can start deep-linking as soon as I have the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you will not be able to do that, you will have to access the source code to do the changes.

Comment: If you could please tell me the specific word for which I can ask the team and they don't give me something else.

Comment: Ask for the **full code**, it's the only way you can build the app after making the changes in AndroidManifest.xml. The code will have a folder named `android`, that is where all the native code is. But again, if you want to make changes at the manifest and then rebuild the app you need the whole folder of the code.

Comment: The probably have some version control (git) if they give you access to the repository than you're all set

Comment: Sure Gabriel, Thanks so much for this valuable information.Also if you happen to know how to achieve this using Firebase then please share the steps or references and what are the prerequisite so that I can start deep-linking as soon as I have the code.